# Listview Adapter problemas com espaços em brancos

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou criando um listView com adpater e estou com um problema, eu precisei adicionar uma imagem no meio da lista para ficar no canto direto, essa imagem é somente uma seta. como posso resolver ai ela ocupa tudo espaço da tela mesmo eu definindo o tamanho da imagem e que é para ela ficar no canto direto.

```
segue XML  lista:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/color_list">



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">



        <TextView
            android:text="@string/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtVencimento"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />



        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtPagamento"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="50dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtNumeDoc"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="50dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtHistorico"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="50dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/caratrblack"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtOrigem"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="50dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />


        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtValoresDesconto"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="50dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtMultaJuros"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="50dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:elevation="50dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />




    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Olhem como ficou esse espaço entre o Histórico e origem, como posso resolver?]

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="teste"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtVencimento"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/user"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtPagamento"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtNumeDoc"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtHistorico"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtOrigem"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />


    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtValoresDesconto"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtMultaJuros"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema. Retirei o Relative e estou usando o LinearLayout.

Você precisava colocar a imagem dentro de outro Linear na horizontal.

Deve ter outros meio, assim achei mais fácil.

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi o que falou no final? Somente a imagem fica em um layout horizontal?

Comment: Ela fica dentro de um LinearLayout horizontal. ficando lado a lado com o textview

Comment: Dessa forma não da para fazer aqui, da erro de Multiple root tags!

Comment: Faltou o inicio do xml. 

Vou editar.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo!